# How to do this without reflection ? Reciever pointer but need to pass slice of non pointer

Tags: go, interface, backend

```
func AddTrailingTimestampData[T HasTimestamp](arr []T, intervalInMs int64, defaultVal T) []T{
    if len(arr) == 0 {
        return arr
    }
    maxTimestamp := arr[0].GetTimestamp()
    for _, item := range arr {
        if item.GetTimestamp() > maxTimestamp {
            maxTimestamp = item.GetTimestamp()
        }
    }

    currentTime := time.Now().UnixMilli()
    for ts := maxTimestamp + intervalInMs; ts <= currentTime; ts += intervalInMs {
        defaultVal.SetTimestamp(ts)
        arr = append(arr, defaultVal)
    }
    return arr
}
```

HasTimestamp interface is

```
type HasTimestamp interface {
    GetTimestamp() int64
    SetTimestamp(ts int64)
}
```

Now the problem for me is to use SetTimeStamp I have to use a pointer receiver.
Now I have an slice of values of a type that implements HasTimestamp but I wouldnt be able to pass it to AddTrailingTimestampData as T would be a pointer to that type and hence we would need []* of that type .

```
any help is appreciated !
```

Comment: `T` can be a pointer type. If you need a pointer receiver, the slice should be of pointer values in the first place.

Comment: I hope you understand my requirement, basically I want to add a default entry for all timestamps from the largest timestamp in the passed slice to till the current time. 
The passed slice is obtained elsewhere and is a slice of structs . I'm trying to write it in a generic way such that I can add trailing timestamp data to any data series I pass

Comment: If you are getting a slice of struct values, which have methods which are supposed to mutate those values, then that is what should be redesigned. If the receiver has a pointer value, then a slice of `T` values cannot satisfy `HasTimestamp` in the first place, hence you can't have a `[]T`. `SetTimeStamp` is not your problem here, the function definition as a whole is the problem. If you are faced with requirements that cannot be met via generics or interfaces, then yes, you must use reflect.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the reply. I'm new to golang.
I totally get your point, however since it would be impossible to call a receiver function using a pointer on a non pointer instance. Is there any possibility where I can do something like 
inputSlice = AddTrailingTimestampData(inputSlice, , )
such that AddTrailingTimestampData returns a new copy with the added timestamps.
Is this a possibility ?

Comment: @JimB Also if I were to use reflect to find the timestamp key in the struct and if i were to use it quite frequently. Is it considered really bad

Comment: Yes you _could_ return a copy of values, or `SetTimestamp` cold return a copy of the value, or many other choices, but none of this matters because your slice of values cannot implement `HasTimestamp` as written to even call `AddTrailingTimestampData`.

Comment: _"Is it considered really bad"_, we can't tell you, that's up to you. Reflection has more overhead, but does it actually matter in your case? Lots of things use reflection, like calling `fmt.Print*` functions, or `encoding/json`, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256713/discussion-between-kevin-tony-and-jimb).

Answer (score -1):

```
func AddTrailingTimestampData[T HasTimestamp](arr []T, intervalInMs int64, getDefaultVal func(ts int64) T) []T {
if len(arr) == 0 {
    return arr
}
maxTimestamp := arr[0].GetTimestamp()
for _, item := range arr {
    if item.GetTimestamp() > maxTimestamp {
        maxTimestamp = item.GetTimestamp()
    }
}

currentTime := time.Now().UnixMilli()
for ts := maxTimestamp + intervalInMs; ts <= currentTime; ts += intervalInMs {
    defaultVal := getDefaultVal(ts)
    arr = append(arr, defaultVal)
}
return arr}
```

This worked for me

Comment: What's the point of the type parameter here? Why not simply `func AddTrailingTimestampData([]HasTimestamp, int64, func(int64) HasTimestamp) []HasTimestamp`?

Comment: @Peter Yes, thanks for the reply . You are right . There is no need for generics here since its expecting the params to satisfy the exact same interface. Thanks . Ill update my answer

Comment: if this works, then the values you have contradicts what you claimed in the question. You can't use a slice of struct values for `[]T` if the interface is satisfied by a pointer receiver. If you can satisfy that interface, you don't need `getDefaultVal`, you can just call `SetTimestamp`

Comment: @JimB Please help me if I am worng.
So for the getter method GetTimestamp I dont need to have a function with pointer receiver as I just want a copy of the ts value. But for SetTimestamp I would need to use pointer in method to update the ts value. So with getDefaultVal I have avoided the need to make the type of my generic T as a pointer as I no longer need to call SetTimestamp in my generic function

Comment: using a function like `getDefaultVal` might be fine, the point is that given the problem as you've described it, you cannot call `AddTrailingTimestampData` with a slice of struct value https://go.dev/play/p/rf9IJUHjSNf. If you can call it, then something in your original problem statement is incorrect (and may be leading you to overcomplicate this whole thing)

Comment: @JimB YES SIR , you are absolutely right. learned a lot from this. I did not want to edit any of the elements in my slice so the slice not being pointers seemed fine to me as all I want is to append new values into it.  But to add into the slice I need to just create a new instance of the type and append to slice. But I am not able to pass the slice to modify by reference , so I am now forced to return the copy from the function and assign it back to the original slice itself

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?** Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code